# Still visible after I deleted my WhatsApp account

Tags: instant-messaging, whatsapp-messenger

I've deleted my [WhatsApp](http://www.whatsapp.com/) account according to the [official instructions](https://whatsapp.zendesk.com/entries/21119703-how-do-i-delete-my-account).

Unfortunately I'm still visible to my friends and they can still send me messages. But with a deleted account that shouldn't be the case — at least in my opinion.

I've already contacted WhatsApp's support but to no avail. Until now I haven't gotten a response.

Do you know what I could do about this issue? Have you already experienced such a problem yourself?

Comment: Yes happens same with me as well.

Comment: @roxan OK. Good to know that I'm not the only one with that problem. Embarrassing that they deliver functionality that doesn't work.

Comment: For BB users there's a similar glitch where 3month old conversations that have been deleted numerous times still reappears everytime I launch whatsapp. I mean yes the app was free and allows me to talk with my friends but for about a year there hasn't been any updates to fix this neither via whatsapp nor BB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PS:** I've just talked to some of my friends and on their phone I disappeared from their Favourites list automatically without manually refreshing.

---

I've just received the following answer from WhatsApp's support team:

> Hi there,
>
> Thanks for confirming your account to be deleted within the WhatsApp
>   settings. Your phone number has been deactivated and it is scheduled
>   to be deleted within 30 days. Therefore, please have your contacts
>   refresh their Favorites List so that you no longer appear as a
>   WhatsApp user.
>
> If you have any other questions or concerns, please feel free to
>   contact us. We would be happy to help!

Sad that my friends have to refresh their Favourites list manually for me to be deleted. Especially when exactly this is described by [WhatsApp's FAQ](https://whatsapp.zendesk.com/entries/21119703-how-do-i-delete-my-account) to be done seemingly automatically when you delete your account:

> Deleting your account will do the following:
>   […]
>   **Delete you from your friends' WhatsApp Favorites lists.**
>   […]