# What will the "last seen date" on WhatsApp be shown when a user uninstalls the app or deletes their account?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I have a WhatsApp user on iPhone with last seen date 5 days ago. I wonder if the user has uninstalled the app, removed their account, or just simply not connected to the internet.

I have read:

1. [Still visible after I deleted my WhatsApp account](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26765)
2. [Whatsapp - last time seen online - what does it mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30781)
3. [WhatsApp FAQs with "delete" keyword](https://faq.whatsapp.com/search?query=delete)

but still unsure. I assume the user didn't block me since I can see their last seen date.

What happens with the last seen date if the user uninstalls WhatsApp or deletes their account? Do I see the last timestamp that the user became online, or is it visible at all?

Answer (score 2):

1. If a user uninstalls WhatsApp, the last seen date will be the last time they use the app.
2. If a user deletes their account, then the account itself will be nonexistent. The user's name will disappear from the user's list itself (just like contacts who don't have WhatsApp aren't listed)

---

Since the last seen date is shown, the user hasn't blocked you. From [WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/21092978),

> There are a couple of indicators that you may be blocked:
>
> - You can no longer see a contact's last seen or online in the chat window. Learn more here.
> - You do not see updates to a contact's profile photo.
> - Any messages sent to a contact who has blocked you will always show one check mark (message sent), and never show a second check mark (message delivered).
> - Any calls you attempt to place will not go through.
>
> If you see all of the indicators above for a contact, this could mean that the user is blocking you. However, there are other possibilities. We have made this intentionally ambiguous in order to protect your privacy when you block someone. Thus, we cannot tell you if you are being blocked by someone else.